# How do I install with home folder on microsd card?

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop that only has a 32gb ssd. I have a 128gb microsd installed for extra storage. I'd like to have my os installed on the ssd, but my home folder and personal files stored on the microsd card. How do I go about doing so? Thanks!

Comment: in that case you will to select the microsd as `/home` partition. Please look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283060/how-do-i-use-my-home-directory-on-a-separate-partition) and [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/), i think these will help.

Comment: Yes, this helped, I essentially done what you said during the installation. Although this part worked flawlessly, I am now unable to encrypt my installation. Meaning, when I don't do any custom partitioning, it gives me the option to encrypt. But now I don't know how to go about doing that. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this with a symbolic link.  I didnt get rid of my ~/ or Home folder but rather mapped paths on a micro-sd card under ~/.

[Here's an answer that explains it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link)

In my case I had an micro-sd called "Extra", with a folder called "Repositories". So my command was

```
ln -s /media/{myprofilename}/Extra/Repositories ~/
```

Now I can access that folder from `~/Repositories` as if it were in the `HOME` folder.

If you're going to user the terminal a lot, I would also set this up for bash aliases as well so if your OS gets wiped away, you can just re-apply your links and life goes on.

Comment: Yeah, this is a neat setup, but completely useless. I was wanting the home folder moved so I could take advantage of the extra space I had available for both file storage and freeing up space on the system partition. So just having a folder redirect me to another folder or essentially being the same folder doesn't help with this particular issue. Thanks for the info though, I appreciate it.